# How to generate random numbers between a range at every 5 numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want random numbers at every 5 numbers in range of 315.
So the result should be like:

2 (from 1 to 5)

7 (from 6 to 10)

11 (from 11 to 15)

16 (from 16 to 20)

24 (from 21 to 25)

29 (from 26 to 30)

33 (from 31 to 35)

36 (from 36 to 40)....and so on till 315.

For more clear view I'm providing 3 example sequences:

1. 1,6,14,20,23,27,31,39...
2. 3,8,15,16,22,29,32,37...
3. 1,10,14,19,21,30,33,36...

I've tried below code:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getRndInteger(1,5); document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = getRndInteger(6,10)">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
</script>
```

but for this I need to create for all 63 intervals.
anybody knows how to simplify this?
I need every number at 5 numbers in series till 315.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean with *"at every 5 numbers"*?

Comment: @NinaScholz meaning 1 to 5, 6 to 10, 11 to 15, 16 to 20 and so on till 315

Comment: The first number maybe `1` or `2` or any number. After that, the next number just be the `previous number + 5`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: @StackOverFlow No it not always should be previous+5. It should be random number.

Comment: For example: the first number is `2`, then the next number maybe `7` or `11`  till 315, right?

Comment: @t3__rry No I already check that out but it is not what I want.

Comment: @StackOverFlow NO. If first number is 2 (from 1 to 5), second number should be 7 (from 6 to 10). and not 11. 11 will be 3rd number.

Comment: I'm sure this is frustrating, because it's clear in your head, but you need to take a breath and explain more clearly what you're trying to do. It would be useful to provide more than one possible sequence, so we're not misled by accidental patterns in one example.

Comment: @IMSoP yes I understand. Please check my edits in question for more clearer view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy way to generate random numbers between a range of 5 (including the borders as mentioned), till the maximum number is reached.

The Running example:

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function example() {
  var maximumNumber = 21;
  var generatedNumbers = [];
  for (var iteration = 1; iteration+1 <= maximumNumber; iteration+=5)
  {
    generatedNumbers.push(randomInteger(iteration, iteration+4));
  }
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = generatedNumbers;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="example()">Generate</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Why are you excluding 1 and 5? I don't see that mentioned in the question anywhere.

Comment: Yeah thanks, edited it. Maybe the examples made me think of it :P Now I see the OP has added examples including border digits ;)

Comment: Thanks this is what I want @Deepak

Comment: @Deepak If I need to add string of 315 in an array. Should it be done with strings too? like var generatedNumbers = ["1 abc", "2 qwe", "3 cbv", "4 fdd"]; ?

Comment: @Khushbu Vaghela Oh no, why I've received `5,6,14,17` if I click the generate button multiple times. Obviously, It's not stable. Having bug @@

Comment: @Phong That's the expected result. Hope you read all the examples provided by the OP :)

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela Do you need to append strings with the generated number? If so, just store the generated number in a variable, and append the string to it before pushing it to the array

Comment: @Deepak I tried it like: var temp = generatedNumbers ;
and before pushing it to the array
temp += "abc";

But "abc" shows at the end of the array like: "1,6,14,19,22,30....313 abc"

I want like "1 abc, 2 asx, 3 ads..."

Comment: "generatedNumbers" is an array. You are appending the string to that array. That's why you get that result. Just keep this inside your for loop: var generatedNumberWithString = randomInteger(iteration, iteration+4) + "abc"; generatedNumbers.push(generatedNumberWithString);

Comment: @Deepak Tahnk you it is working but I want different string on different numbers. not only "abc". Is it possible?

Comment: 1 abc,2 xyz,3 pqr and like this on each number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227517/discussion-between-khushbu-vaghela-and-deepak).

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the outer range with increment by five and take a random offset of max five.

```js
for (let i = 0, l = 315; i <= l; i += 5) {
    console.log(i += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
}
```

Comment: Oh no, the result may be `3 10 17` ?? It doesn't be `+5` each time :(

Comment: @StackOverFlow, it doesn't have to. please see the example of op.

Comment: I just ran this a couple of times, and one of them included the sequence "22,27,36,42", which I don't think meets the OP's requirements - note the jump of 9 in the middle there.

Comment: Oh, I see the bug now: you're adding a fixed offset of 5 _and_ a random offset to the same variable, on every loop. So the number goes up by between 5 and 10 each time, which could never generate the example sequence 2,7,11 (offset of 4 between the second and third numbers).

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this (I didnt tested, but it came to my mind):

```
 <script>
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  var i = min;
  var numbers = []
  for ( i; i < max; i+5)
   numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - i+ 1) + i));
 return numbers;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the first number may be any integer ranging `from 1 to 315`.

After that, the subsequent number equals `the previous number + 5`.

```js
var firstNumber = 0;

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  var result = [randomNumber];
  while(randomNumber + 5 <= 315){
    randomNumber += 5;
    result.push(randomNumber);
  }
  
  return result.join(',');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = randomIntFromInterval(1,315)">Click Me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

> **Old version answer**

Besides, you can add more of a button named `Reset` to random it again.

```js
var firstNumber = 0;

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  if(firstNumber ===0) {
    firstNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    return firstNumber;
  }
  
  firstNumber += 5; 
  return firstNumber >= 315 ? 315 : firstNumber;
}

function reset(){
 firstNumber = 0;
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = randomIntFromInterval(1,315)">Click Me</button>
<button id="Reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The question has been edited to clarify that the sequence is _not_ just adding 5 each time.

Comment: @StackOverFlow Thank you but I want series of numbers. In one click all the series should be shown.

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela As I mentioned in my answer, always break your problems down: whether the sequence is output one item at a time, pushed into an array, built into a string with commas; and whether it's triggered by a click, or when the page loads, or when the clock strikes 12 ... all those are details you can change for _any_ of the suggestions on this page. Get the algorithm right first, and then you can reuse it however you like.

Comment: @IMSoP yes right but still the series does not start from 1 to 5 ! and it always adds 5 which I do not want

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela Sure, I wasn't saying this was necessarily the right algorithm, I just wanted to stress the importance of looking at _algorithms_ as separate from _how they're used_.

Comment: @IMsoP I've just updated my answer based on your new requirement. Pls take a look at it, Thanks.

Comment: @Khushbu Vaghela You should take a look at this answer one again.

Comment: @StackOverFlow You've missed the more important change, which is adding 5 each time isn't the sequence the OP wanted. See the updated question, and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of programming is breaking a problem down into smaller parts, and then building back up to the full solution.

In this case, we can break the problem down like this:

1. Create a set of 63 bands: 1 to 5, 6 to 10, etc
2. Pick a random number in each band

For part 2, you already have the `getRndInteger` function you show in the question:

```
    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
    }
```

Part 1 can be done a few ways, but perhaps the easiest to understand is a simple `while` loop:

```js
let min=1;
let max=5;
while ( max <= 315 ) {
    console.log(min, max);
    min += 5;
    max += 5;
}
```

So now all we need to do is put the two together:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

let min=1;
let max=5;
while ( max <= 315 ) {
    let next = getRndInteger(min, max);
    console.log(next);
    min += 5;
    max += 5;
}
```

Comment: Why does it start from 65 to 70 ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems to be something wrong with the code snippet widget, I think - maybe it just has a maximum number of lines it can show? If I paste it into an actual browser console, all the numbers are there, and hopefully the code should be clear enough to see that it does start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop to find the all random numbers in the range you want, change the max and min values in each loop. Since all numbers are requested, you must add them to an array.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = randomIntFromInterval()">Click Me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


function randomIntFromInterval() { 
// min and max included 
  let min=0;
  let max=5;
  let numberOfList=[];
  for(let i=0;i<63;i++){
     let randomNumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min  +1) + min);
     numberOfList.push(`${randomNumber}`);
     min=min+5;
     max=max+5;
  } return numberOfList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) for simplicity and cryptographic security:

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 315; i += 5){
  console.log(rando(i, i + 4));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think like this. When Math.random() generates 0, get 1. And Math.random() generates 1, you get 5. So  you can write this function like this:

```
Math.floor(1 + 4 * Math.random())
```

so you can generate like this.

```js
for(let i = 0; i<315; i+=5)
{ 
  console.log(Math.floor(i + 1 + 4 * Math.random()))
}
```